# Navigate in layer parameters

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I've a layer who contain many parameters like number. I try to "navigate" in this layer for make a specific action.

The schematic structure of my layer look like :

```
object : [a] - item (1) - [o] - name (Name layer) - [o] - source (14) - [o] - number (14)
```

for take the name of my layer I'wrote (return "Name layer") :

```
map.getLayers().item(1).get('name')
```

but if I want to make an action on the layer "Name layer" and the number "14", how can I do that ?

I tried : `map.getLayers().item(1).get('name').item(14).get('number');`

But it's don't that.

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution. You can make a loop in your object like that :

```
for (var a = 0; a < length; a++) {

    console.log (layers.a[i].o['source'].o[a].o['number']);

}
```